# How to use code commit repository which is created in one account in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, aws-codebuild

I have created my aws code commit repository in another account and now I want to use it in a different account in my pipeline.
I found this article:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html

But this article is using s3 which will be easy by using bucket policy. However for using codecommit repository created in one account and used in a pipeline in another account I did not find anything. Is it possible at all? I would appreciate any help

Comment: I just had to do this and have put the steps to do this in the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169376/1495728)