# Codepipeline checkout a codecommit repo in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am trying to checkout the Codecommit repo in account A from a Codepipeline in account B. I have created the role in A for the codepipeline to assume from account B.

Once I run the pipeline, I get

> Invalid action configuration
>   The AWS CodeCommit repository "sample-repo" does not exist.

I would like to understand what could have caused this ?

Comment: I just had to do this, see my answer in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169376/1495728)